# Google Sheet - Filter by ROW and COLUMN

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to do something seems simple, but dunno how to.

I would liken to create simple timesheet report by week
Here is an example of what I want to do
[image]

But I don't know how to filtering by row (project or employee) AND grouping/summing by column (week number). I tried with filter, query, {range1\ range2} etc.

The expected resultats are in green on the sheet. It can be one formula for all datas or one formula by cell, it's not a problem for me

Google sheet doc example : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14H8GgMCWCDXuHm5q34Nz1kxUR12NO3tQqOeQeOOjaDY/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks a lot for all the time you will spend to help me :)

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(C5:I="";;B5:B&"×"&C2:I2&"×"&C5:I)); "×"); 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3)
  where Col2 is not null
  group by Col1
  pivot Col2
  label Col1'Employee'"))
```

and:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(C5:I="";;A5:A&"×"&C2:I2&"×"&C5:I)); "×"); 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3)
  where Col2 is not null
  group by Col1
  pivot Col2
  label Col1'Project'"))
```

[image]